# "base documents" vs. "basic documents" for commonly referenced sources

Tags: terminology, technical

As a non-native speaker, I might be mislead here. I tend to prefer *base documents* because I think *base* is a better word for something used as a *foundation* - and *basic* might translate to *simple*. However, when searching for both terms, it appears they are used almost interchangeably, and I have a hard time finding out if one of the two is preferred, or maybe just regionally preferred (AE vs BE or the like).

The exact context is a good term for documents like standards or laws used as references or sources for technical specifications. The term references doesn't seem to be exactly right, because a *reference* can be anything, and a *base/basic document* might be a better hint towards the fact that the documents are referenced similar to a tree structure, i.e. the specifications cite a standard, and never the other way round.

Comment: The word "core" is often used, like "The core documentation", which is close to what you're talking about I think.

Comment: I'd say that by default, the ***base** documents* would be those documents which actually form the ***basis*** "on top of which" all the rest of the documentation is "built" (those documents *must* be present in the full documentation repository, so they can be referred back to). But ***basic*** documents has no special meaning beyond the fact that they don't go into any great detail. The rest of the documentation might not or might not  refer to them. People who document a system must be familiar with any ***base** documents*, but they might not know or care about ***basic** documents*.

Comment: basic reference documents: google it, you'll see the variety of tech/admin contexts where it appears.

Answer (score 1):

The collocation "[basic reference](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22basic%20reference%22&newwindow=1&sca_esv=3fe0b148ff4f6c90&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACQVn08695SUpdIKN896qg38FOMPkuG0Yg:1706697699335&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvju6wuIeEAxW-q4kEHW_mAqAQ0pQJKAV6BAgDEAg&biw=1366&bih=669&dpr=1)" is universally used and understood, so best to go with it.

The term **basic reference** is broadly encompassing and can include scholarly works when the context is scholarship but also things like the tariff schedule when the context is the importing business, training manuals, and standards documents in any domain. The core idea is that the work is foundational in the given domain.

**base documents** on the other hand is not a collocation and its meaning is not likely to be understood.

> The OED is a basic reference.
>
> The Harmonized Tariff Schedule is a basic reference for customs brokers.
>
> "The Standard Classification of Goods (SCG) is the standard used by Statistics Canada to collect commodity data and to uniquely identify such data in data banks. [...]  since the manual is **a basic reference** rather than an operating manual, it has been decided beginning with the 1992 manual to discontinue issuing an annual updating supplement."(https://www.statcan.gc.ca/en/subjects/standard/scg/scgintro1996)

You wrote:

> The term references doesn't seem to be exactly right, because a reference can be anything, and a base/basic document might be a better hint towards the fact that the documents are referenced similar to a tree structure, i.e. the specifications cite a standard, and never the other way round.

Your hope that "document" might "hint" at a tree structure is wishful thinking, and "document" nowadays is no more specific than "reference"; indeed it can be almost anything, from a love note to a parking ticket to a manifesto.

Comment: But does have the meaning that the OP wants?

Comment: @psmears: Yes it does have the meaning that OP wants.  Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: At the time I wrote the comment, your answer contained no indication at all of what the term meant, only a google search that showed it is used...

Comment: Yes, I was in the process of adding to the answer.

Comment: +1. Frame challenges are sometimes, as here, the correct way to proceed on a site aimed at non-basic studies.

Comment: *basic reference documents*

Answer (score 0):

Both constructions are grammatically correct and will be understood by many English speakers, and there are some alternatives that enjoy regional preferences. Both imply the documents imply a "basis", which can be used synonymously with "foundation".

Comment: Your answer reads as opinion and would be more convincing were it backed up by references. You also raise tangential ines of thought (regional preferences, foundation) that merely confuse unless you show how they relate to the question.

Answer (score -1):

You will be helped by Google Ngram Viewer for the search terms **base document,basic document** in British English and American English - **[CLICK HERE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=base%20document%3A%20eng_gb_2019%2Cbasic%20document%3A%20eng_gb_2019%2Cbase%20document%3A%20eng_us_2019%2Cbasic%20document%3A%20eng_us_2019&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3#)** You will note that below the graph, there are links to each of the terms divided into time periods. You should look at these to get the context. A cursory glance shows that whereas both terms are used, "basic document" is more frequently used.

> I think base is a better word for something used as a foundation - and basic ***might*** translate to simple.

This is completely unwarranted. "Base" ***might*** translate as

OED

> 7. a. Of a low or inferior quality or standard; poor, inadequately good.

> 1990   C. McCullough First Man in Rome 220   *How can you besmirch the word ‘love’ with whatever base imitation you have experienced?*

The importance of context cannot be overstated in English.

Comment: The word 'base' has other meanings also. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/base